# Splitting tex file via commands

Tags: macros, input

I'd like to rearrange a document with snippets at will.
It could be done via \input but the snippets are too small to be put in individual files.
If put in a \newcommand the # from code listings confuse the compiler though.
I am looking for something like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand\snippetA{ 
\begin{lstlisting}
    something 
\end{lstlisting}
}
\newcommand\snippetB{ 
\begin{lstlisting}
    else 
\end{lstlisting}
}
\newcommand\snippetC{ 
\begin{lstlisting}
    code # | $ \% 
\end{lstlisting}
}


\begin{document}

\snippetA
\snippetC
\snippetB


\end{document}
```

> Illegal parameter number in definition of \part1. }

Is there a way to tell Latex not to expect arguments or another \newcommand macro?

Comment: you can not use verbatim related commands (such as listings) in the arguments of other commands. You can use `##` to get a `#` in `\snippetA` but verb/listings etc will not see it as a verbatim `#`

Comment: That is the issue I'm trying to solve. I could put the listings in separate files, that wouldn't be a huge improvement though.

Comment: it's a basic tex syntax restriction, not really a soluable issue. In special cases you can use `\detokenize` or  `\scantokens` or `\NewDocumentCommand`  `v` arguments or ... But they all have tricky conditions on when and how they work. Using separate files _is_ the mechanism. or with luatex you could use lua strings

Comment: Also it would help if you provided a proper example that you wanted to work, if you just replaced  `\snippetA `  by `# something` you would still get an error andt if you replace `\verb|# something|` by `\verb|\snippetA|`  it does not matter how you define `\snippetA` (or if you use `\input` ) as commands are not recognised in `\verb` (or `listings`, mostly)

Comment: So you want to have a better overview in your .tex file? If so think along these lines: A) Use a different editor (in parallel); e.g. Notepad++ and many others let you collapse e.g. environments. Check out the programming communities for editors. B) Use a (novel-) writing tool like Scrivener, or other authoring tools, which allows you to manipulate, reorder, hide etc. various code parts; compile there and copy into e.g. Texmaker to create pdf. Treat preambles etc. as ... sth. you just write.

Comment: TexStudio can collapse blocks too but it messes with tabs when copying code segments. 
It is just more convenient to move a single line around than entire blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By far the most robust way to handle fragments involving catcode changes is to use external files. You can still use a single file for source editing, as shown here

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname-A}
\begin{lstlisting}
    something 
\end{lstlisting}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname-B}
\begin{lstlisting}
    else 
\end{lstlisting}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname-C}
\begin{lstlisting}
    code # | $ \% 
\end{lstlisting}
\end{filecontents}



\begin{document}

\input{\jobname-A}
\input{\jobname-C}
\input{\jobname-B}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own defining-command which reads the definition-text under verbatim-category-code-régime and defines a macro where things are passed to `\scantokens`—however approaches based on `\scantokens` might probably not intertwine well with SyncTeX which is a problem for some users:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\catcode`\Z=14 %
\catcode`\%=12 Z
\@firstofone{Z
  \endgroup
  \newcommand*\defineVerbatim[1]{Z
    \begingroup
    \catcode`\^^I=12 Z
    \@defineVerbatim{#1}Z
  }Z
  \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{Z
    \NewDocumentCommand\@defineVerbatim{m+v}{Z
      \endgroup
      \@ifdefinable#1{Z
        \DeclareRobustCommand*#1{Z
          \texorpdfstring{Z
            \begingroup
            \newlinechar=\endlinechar
            \scantokens{\endgroup#2%}Z
          }{Z
            Z Using snippet-macros in pdf-strings like bookmarks does not work out.
            Z Therefore instances of snippet maqcros shall be removed in pdf-strings and
            Z a warning-message about this shall be delivered.
            \pdfstringdefWarn{#1}Z
          }Z
        }Z
      }Z
    }Z
  }{Z
    \NewDocumentCommand\@defineVerbatim{m+v}{Z
      \endgroup
      \@ifdefinable#1{Z
        \DeclareRobustCommand*#1{Z
          \begingroup
          \newlinechar=\endlinechar
          \scantokens{\endgroup#2%}Z
        }Z
      }Z
    }Z
  }Z
}%

% Indenting does matter with \defineVerbatim's second argument!
% It is relied on \defineVerbatim getting its arguments by reading
% and tokenizing .tex-input-file.

\defineVerbatim\snippetA{%
\begin{lstlisting}
something 
\end{lstlisting}
}

\defineVerbatim\snippetB{%
\begin{lstlisting}
else 
\end{lstlisting}
}

\defineVerbatim\snippetC{%
\begin{lstlisting}
code # | $ \% 
\end{lstlisting}
}%

\defineVerbatim\snippetIndentingDoesMatter{%
\begin{lstlisting}
    code # | $ \% 
\end{lstlisting}
}%

\defineVerbatim\snippetIndentingDoesMatterMultiline{%
\begin{lstlisting}
    code # | $ \% 
  code # | $ \% 
code # | $ \% 
\end{lstlisting}
}%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\snippetA
\snippetC
\snippetB
\snippetIndentingDoesMatter
\snippetIndentingDoesMatterMultiline

% Macros defined in terms of \defineVerbatim do not work out in pdf-strings.
% Thus in case of using hyperref the following triggers a warning
%   Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
%   (hyperref)                removing `\snippetA' on input line ...
% when creating the bookmark from \section's argument.

\section{Bla \snippetA}

\end{document}
```

[image]